# Zend form change matching error

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

I add validator to email element:

```
$usr_email->addValidator('Db_NoRecordExists', true, array('users', 'usr_email'));
```

And now have error message: **A record matching 'admin@example' was found**

I want change this error, but I want that will display inserted email

**A email  'admin@example' already exist in database**
I try , but email not disply ant html tags

```
addErrorMessage("**This email **strong text** address already exist.**");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%value%` placeholder in the error message, it will be replaced with the actual value.

Example:

```
$usr_email->addValidator('Db_NoRecordExists', true, array(
    'users', 
    'usr_email', 
    'messages' => array(
        'recordFound' => 'A email %value% already exist in database'
    )));
```